I think we **could** help

What is the difference?
(1) I think we could help.
(2) I think we can help.
Does "could" here express less certainy than "can"?

"Could" may be used when there is an implicit condition. For example it might be understood in context to mean:

I think we could help (if they want to be helped).

Other conditions are possible.  The implied condition makes the "could" form more tentative, and so may be used just because a tentative form is preferred.
